# Factory Pattern/ArrayList/Interface Issue

Tags: java, arraylist, interface, factory-pattern

I am using a factory pattern to create different types of elevators using the `ElevatorMover` interface. The factory is store the elevators in an `ArrayList` of `ElevatorMover` objects. When I retrieve an elevator [`ElevatorArrayList.get(i)`] from the `ArrayList`, I am unable to call `PassengerElevator` methods. Only `ElevatorMover` methods (which are not implemented of course).

What am I failing to do here?

Here is the code I'm trying to call in main

```
// make elevator 1 go to the 11th floor
testBuilding.getElevator(1).moveUp(11);
```

This is my interface

```
public interface ElevatorMover {

public void moveUp(int i);

public void moveDown(int i);

public void openDoors();
```

This is the PassengerElevator method

```
@Override
public void moveUp(int i) {
    while (currentFloor != i) {
        setCurrentFloor(currentFloor++);
    }
}
```

The error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Elevator.Building.getElevator(Building.java:109)
    at Elevator.ElevatorSimulatorMain.main(ElevatorSimulatorMain.java:34)
```

Building.class constructor

```
private ArrayList<Floor> floorArrayList; // the ArrayList of floors in the building
private ArrayList<ElevatorMover> elevatorArrayList; // the ArrayList of elevators in the building

public Building(int numFloors, int numElevators) {

    this.numFloors = numFloors;
    this.numElevators = numElevators;

    // create each floor
    if (numFloors > 0) // Must have 1 or more floors
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numFloors; i++) {
            floorArrayList.add(new Floor(i));
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Building must have 1 or more floors.");
    }

    // create each elevator.
    if (numElevators > 0) //  Must have 1 or more elevators
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numElevators; i++) {
        elevatorArrayList.add(ElevatorFactory.build("Passenger", i));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Building must have 1 or more elevators.");
    }
}
```

ElevatorFactory build method

```
public static ElevatorMover build(String type, int elevID) {

    if (type.equals("Passenger")) {
        return new PassengerElevator(elevID);
    }
    else return null; // don't know what this is
}
```

The getElevator method

```
public ElevatorMover getElevator(int i) {
    return elevatorArrayList.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Code snippet please.

Comment: Why do you think PassengerElevator methods should be available when the method presumably returns an ElevatorMover?

Comment: @AmirAfghani perhaps I am misunderstanding what an interface does, but I am using a interface to A) provide common methods amongst different types of elevators and B) allow my various types of elevators to be grouped in an ArrayList.

Comment: What do you know about method overriding?

Comment: @Vwin I added some code

Comment: @immibis I probably fall into the intermediate-beginner category. Tell me what you're thinking about, please. I can hopefully learn from it.

Comment: Is it giving you an error when you are trying to call `moveup()`?

Comment: Tell us what is happening clearly like an error or not the expected value? Also it woul be nice if yo add PassengerElevator definition

Comment: @Vwin I am getting a NullPointerException. I shall add the error message above. Also something to point out, my IDE (NetBeans) is not bringing up any methods for use besides the interface's when offering suggestions. I'm not sure if this is just an IDE thing that is solved at run-time or if it's an actual type issue.

Comment: Are you sure getElevator has ElevatorMover objects? What is testBuilding? Can you add in the sample code

Comment: @juunas please see the post to Vwin about the error above. I wasn't allow to make two tags in the same comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Vwin, I just ran a test to check this and it failed. So, I guess the issue is the adding of the PassengerElevator, etc. to the ArrayList. I will post code above. testBuilding is an instance of the Building class. A Building object contains the number of floors and elevators in the building. It also contains two ArrayLists for the floors and elevators, which are created and filled when an instance of Building is created.

Comment: `at Elevator.Building.getElevator(Building.java:109)` This means that the exception throws in `Building.getElevator` at line 109 so...show us `getElevator`.

Comment: Yes. Show getElevator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you did not create elevatorArrayList. Example

`List<ElevatorMover> elevatorArrayList = new ArrayList<ElevatorMover>();`

```
private ArrayList<ElevatorMover> elevatorArrayList; // This is just declaring not creating elevatorArrayList
```

Comment: I did. I shall post it above.

Comment: You just declared the variable elevatorArrayList. You have to create an ArrayList using the new operator as mentioned above

Comment: @Vmin You, sir or madam, are amazing. You can be certain that this will be a lesson I shall always carry with me so this doesn't happen again. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you call an interface method - actually *any* method (except static methods), the method that is called is the one in the actual class (or as close to it as possible) - not the one in the type that the reference is.

Consider this code:

```
class A {
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("In A");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("In B");
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("In C");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new C();
        a.doStuff(); // Prints "In C", NOT "In A", because the object is a C, even though the variable's type is "reference to A"
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you have a reference to a `PassengerElevator` and you call `moveUp`, then it will call the `moveUp` method in `PassengerElevator` no matter what type the reference is (as long as the reference's type actually has a `moveUp` method).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Vwin how isn't it? I understood the question as "This won't work because `ElevatorMover.moveUp` is called, not `PassengerElevator.moveUp`, right?"

Comment: @Vmin thanks for this! This does support how I understand interfaces and overriding methods. So, at least I know that my method call is probably not the issue. It seems to be an issue with how I am filling my ArrayList